# dpkg dependency problems due to different installed versions

Tags: apt, dpkg, dependencies, architecture

Can someone help me to solve this problem? Below is the output when performing `sudo dpkg --configure -a`
Output:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libapt-pkg4.12:i386:
 libapt-pkg4.12:i386 depends on libc6 (>= 2.15); however:
  Package libc6:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libapt-pkg4.12:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: error processing package libgcc1:amd64 (--configure):
 package libgcc1:amd64 1:4.9.1-0ubuntu1 cannot be configured because libgcc1:i386 is at a different version (1:4.9.3-0ubuntu4)
dpkg: error processing package libgcc1:i386 (--configure):
 package libgcc1:i386 1:4.9.3-0ubuntu4 cannot be configured because libgcc1:amd64 is at a different version (1:4.9.1-0ubuntu1)
dpkg: error processing package gcc-4.9-base:amd64 (--configure):
 package gcc-4.9-base:amd64 4.9.1-0ubuntu1 cannot be configured because gcc-4.9-base:i386 is at a different version (4.9.3-0ubuntu4)
dpkg: error processing package gcc-4.9-base:i386 (--configure):
 package gcc-4.9-base:i386 4.9.3-0ubuntu4 cannot be configured because gcc-4.9-base:amd64 is at a different version (4.9.1-0ubuntu1)
dpkg: error processing package libc6:amd64 (--configure):
 package libc6:amd64 2.19-0ubuntu6.6 cannot be configured because libc6:i386 is at a different version (2.19-0ubuntu6.7)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libapt-pkg4.12:i386
 libgcc1:amd64
 libgcc1:i386
 gcc-4.9-base:amd64
 gcc-4.9-base:i386
 libc6:amd64
```

Comment: Install it manualy? `sudo apt-get install libc6-i386`

Comment: Thanks for the reply .. just did that and come back                                                     sudo apt-get install libc6-i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libc6-i386 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  libc6

E: Package 'libc6-i386' has no installation candidate

Comment: what about `sudo apt-get install libc6`?

Comment: also not working.. coming more errors    no way to downgrade and then upgrade?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add the output of `apt-cache policy libgcc1:amd64 libgcc1:i386 gcc-4.9-base:amd64 gcc-4.9-base:i386` and then notify me with a comment when you're done.